# Angle bracket (<) without triggering html code

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [printing “<html>” using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505047/printing-html-using-html)

How can I put the < symbol literally into html text without invoking html stuffs.

Comment: The character “<” is the LESS THAN character. If you actually meant an angle bracket, then you can use U+2329 LEFT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET “〈” or some similar character as such (with many caveats).

Answer (score 223):

Use "`&lt;`".  Similarly, you can use "`&gt;`" for >, or "`&amp;`" for &.

These are called HTML "entities".  You can learn more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 95):

Use `&lt;` for **<**.

Or `&gt;` for **>**.