# Ignore <tag> in html

Tags: html, css, tags

I would like to write the following text into my html webpage: `ClosedRange<Double>`

However, when I put that text in a paragraph tag, `<p>ClosedRange<Double></p>`, the  tag is obviously ignored when the webpage renders.

Any suggestions on how to ignore the tags around `<Double>`?

Comment: Use html entities https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Thanks. Just added that as a formal answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Angle bracket (<) without triggering html code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14659240/4642212). `<` and `>` are called angle brackets. `<Double>` is a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use html entities https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref.

```
<p>ClosedRange&lt;Double&gt;</p>
```

Renders as:

```
ClosedRange<Double>
```

Credit to @niclaslindgren

Comment: Although technically it is only the left bracket '<' that needs to be replaced with '&lt;' and not strictly also the right (although it will obviously do no harm).