# How to display data written between angular brackets including brackets

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have stored a c++ code snipet in javascript variable like this:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="Assets/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script>
                        var s = "#include<iostream.h>#include<conio.h>";
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#btn").click(function(){
                                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s;
                            });
                        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">show</button>
        <h1><p id="text"></p></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

on the JSP page when I click the button it prints only "#include#include". It is not printing the whole thing as i assign to the variable s.

So, my question is, How I can print the things between the "<>" angle brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this demo, you should use escape character for showing html to browser
like `&lt;` for < , `&gt;` for > and so on.
or you can also try text() function of ajax. it will escape your text as per require.

Like this:

```
 $("#text1").text(s1);
```

Check this snippet.

```js
var s = "#include&lt;iostream.h&gt;#include&lt;conio.h&gt;";
var s1 = "#include<iostream.h>#include<conio.h>";
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = s;
    $("#text1").text(s1);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="Assets/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">show</button>
        <h1><p id="text"></p></h1>
      <h1><p id="text1"></p></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use HTML entities to represent these characters.

Replace "<" with `&lt;`, and ">" with `&gt;`

Here is a complete list of entities: [Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Answer (score 0):

> on the JSP page when I click the button it prints only "#include#include". It is not printing the whole thing as i assign to the variable s.

Because , jquery interprets the `<>` tags inside it .

> How I can print the things between the "<>" angle brackets.

To print the elements inside the tags as it is , you need to escape them either as `&lt;` or  `&LT;` Similarly for the other one as `&gt;` or `&GT;`

Have a look at [printing "<html>" using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505047/printing-html-using-html?s=3|1.0014).