# Writing html tags with no effects in a ebook (xhtml)

Tags: html, xhtml, epub

I'm writing a tutorial book (epub with xhtml) and i want to include for explanations some blocks of html.

The problem is when i write them they have effect on my page... i have tried to include them with "pre" tags but this way corrupt my page. I also try surround with "code" tags but same result. For example i want to write this line in my tutorial :

```
<body><head></head></body>
```

I use the editor of the "calibre" software.

Anyone had this problem ?

thanks by advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us your code and provide more details so we can better understand your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hello and thx for ur welcome...i added an example of what i want to write in my book but just as a text...

Comment: oups i've found the solution i need to replace < by &lt; and > by &gt;  Thanks for ur help anyway !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing "<html>" using html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505047/printing-html-using-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to replace  `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`.