# How to display HTML textarea snippets in textarea tag?

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, special-characters

Is there any way that I could display HTML snippets in HTML page using textarea??

the following code is work

```
<textarea readonly='true'>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is some text</p>
</textarea>
```

But when I put `<textarea>` tag in textarea is not work

```
<textarea readonly='true'>
        <textarea arows="4" cols="50">Hello World</textarea>
</textarea>
```

any idea to Display textarea snippets in `textarea` tag??

Thank you very much

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ga0bfpue/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printing "<html>" using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505047/printing-html-using-html)

Comment: You should escape the [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp): `&lt;textarea arows="4" cols="50"&gt;Hello World&lt;/textarea&gt;`